# Can an iOS app inherit a Settings bundle through a dependency framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks, settings.bundle

I am developing an SDK and would like to expose some configurable items to the settings app.

Is it possible to define these at my library level and have them inherited by the consuming app so the client developer doesn't need to add to her bundle?